# How do I use the sitefinity dynamic content controller?

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity, sitefinity-feather

I am trying to use the `DynamicContentController` by inheritance

```
    [ControllerToolboxItem(Name = "TT_FAQ_test_MVC", Title = "TT_FAQ_test_MVC",
   SectionName = "TT Widgets")]
    [DesignerUrl("~/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend/Designer/Master/DynamicContent")]
```

How do I use the default designer without needing to implement it myself?
I tried using the DesignerUrl but no luck with it, is my path incorrect?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve by inheriting the DynamicContentController? Your path looks correct, are there any errors if you open dev toolbar? any failed requests?

Comment: I was being lazy and wanted to easily implement the master/detail views, but decided to just put in the effort and get it done the proper ways. Thanks though, appreciate your help!